# Magic Mouse2 keep loosing connection which keyboard and Magic Trackpad work fine

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, magic-trackpad, macos

I have a Magic Mouse 2, Magic Trackpad and Apple keyboard. From time to time, mainly when I have higher CPU usage, my mouse drops it's connection. I have my trackpad next to it and it is still working fine, as is my keyboard.

I think I have narrowed it down to the amount of screen I have attached to my computer. At work I have a Dell 43" 4k screen and at home I have (2) 27, 1(34 wide) and (1) USB Screen. If I have all screens running then my mouse drops more frequently.

I have a 2018 Macbook Pro 15 with 16gb memory, i7, 4gb video memory

Comment: When you say it "drops" do you have to reconnect it or does it start working again?

Comment: @Allan It will reconnect in a few seconds and then it works for minutes or hours.

Comment: Are you certain it's not lagging?  Disconnecting and lagging are two different symptoms.  Check your BT connections from the menu bar to be certain that it in fact has disconnected.

Comment: @Allan I get the little mouse connection lost overlay each time it happens. I will try to take a screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was related to a cheaper dongle for HDMI. Once I removed the dongle my mouse problem disappeared.

It is related to this issue. I did not try wrapping the dongle in foil, but removing it completely solved my mouse dropping issue.

[Macbook loses network connection when connecting external display](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142929/macbook-loses-network-connection-when-connecting-external-display)