# MacBook Pro 2017 Loses Internet Connection When Connected to LG 27ML600M-B 27" Monitor

Tags: network, display, wifi, hdmi

Similar to [this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142929/macbook-loses-network-connection-when-connecting-external-display) Apple StackExchange question, I have a MacBook facing a similar problem.

When the MacBook in question is connected to LG 27ML600M-B 27" via HDMI one of two things happens:

1. The device refuses to connect to a WiFi or Mobile Hotspot
2. If the device is connected to the WiFi or Mobile Hotspot, it refuses to load any pages or get any pings (i.e. `ping 8.8.8.8`)

I've attempted some of the suggestions from that thread:

1. Change the refresh rate of the monitor (from 60Hz) to either 50Hz or 75Hz (currently at 75Hz).
2. Wrap aluminum foil/tinfoil (including the tip) of the cable, for a good 30-40cm of the HDMI cable. I did also wrap another cable (the power cable) around the HDMI cable as well.

I sadly do not have access to my flat's WiFi admin panel, thus I cannot change the WiFi's (2.4 GHz) channel (or even check if it's between 11 and 14), as suggested [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7872207)

Specs:

1. MacBook Pro 2017
2. LG 27ML600M-B 27"
3. [Apple Macbook Thunderbolt 3 HUB + 4K HDMI + Card Reader + 2 USB 3.0 (Silver)](https://www.amazon.com.tr/dp/B07QMLBTB9?ref=ppx_pop_mob_ap_share)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Strange, could it be that Mac thinks it is connected to Ethernet ?thus ignoring WiFi ? Check in About this Mac, System Info

Comment: @Ruskes there's no Ethernet port on the adapter, so I am unsure. But then again, the ethernet in Networking settings is blank.

Comment: OK, it was just a idea, so it is not that. Did you test that HDMI cable directly with TV ?

Comment: Also take look at WiFi in the system preferences, for example what country does it says, and other parameters.

Comment: Next, hold option key, and click on WiFi icon in the top bar, that will give you more information, and allow settings.